# Handling Net::ReadTimeout error in HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, httparty

I am using httparty (0.13.1) gem. I am making series of API calls using httparty. Some of my initial API calls succeeded, but the later calls fail consecutively. I have added a timeout of 180 seconds. I searched google but I can not find any solution still. I am struggling due to this for a long time.

**My code:**

```
response = HTTParty.get("http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=marketdatav2", timeout: 180)
```

**Error:**

```
A Net::ReadTimeout occurred in background at 2014-10-05 11:42:06 UTC :
```

I don't know whether this time out is working? I feel 180 seconds is more than enough to retrieve the response because the default timeout is 60 seconds. If I want to handle Net read timeout error, Is there a way to do it? I want to return nil if this error occurs.
Or Is there a best solution to avoid happening this error?

Comment: Have you got solved this? am also having same problem for series of API calls. timeout not working for me too.

Answer (score 19):

Had a similar problem with a different module, and in my case it likely succeeds if retried, so I catch the timeout and retry.

```
  max_retries = 3
  times_retried = 0

  begin
    #thing that errors sometimes

  rescue Net::ReadTimeout => error
    if times_retried < max_retries
      times_retried += 1
      puts "Failed to <do the thing>, retry #{times_retried}/#{max_retries}"
      retry
    else
      puts "Exiting script. <explanation of why this is unlikely to recover>"
      exit(1)
    end
  end
```

Left here in case someone else finds it helpful.

Answer (score 7):

you could use `rescue` to handling your timeout exception:

```
begin
  HTTParty.get("http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=marketdatav2", timeout: 180)
rescue Net::ReadTimeout
  nil
end
```